# How to get a connection string to connect to cmdsql server created in Linux terminal?

Tags: sql-server, linux, terminal

I need to have a way to connect in Visual Studio Code to the server I created when configure the cmdsql in Linux. There is a way to do this?

I will explain a little better:

1. First I connect to the localhost server on Linux terminal using the next command. With this I can do querys directly on the terminal, to the databases hosted in server. I can create databases, tables, insert, update and more.

   sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 123456
2. I get the mssql extension for Visual Studio Code. There is a button '+ Add Connection' where I need to pass a connection string for connect to SQL Server.

What I need? I need a connection string to connect in Visual Studio to localhost server I created on Linux terminal.

Edit: Aditionally I will use this connection string to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc with Python based API I'm developing.

Comment: You don't specifically need a connection string. When you click on the `+` button to add a connection it starts a wizard that prompts you 1) for the host name and/or instance, e.g.: `FooServerName,1433` or `BarServerName\InstanceName`, 2) the default database to use (can be blank), 3) the authentication type, e.g.: SQL Login, 4) SQL username and password, 5) a friendly name to use for the connection.

Comment: That's useful! Aditionally, how can I know the InstanceName generated for my connection? I have the server name, localhost, but according to your answer I need to concatenate the instance name. Example: localhost/NewInstance

Comment: If you know the port number prefer to use that over the instance name. Instance name resolution requires that the SQL Browser service is running (and accessible) on udp/1433, and that's unlikely to be the case when SQL Server is hosted on Linux because the Browser service is [unsupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019#Unsupported) there.